# compiling pr2_build_map_gazebo_demo on debian

Tags: ros-fuerte, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The compilation stops on debian/amd64 because the package `pr2_mechanism_model` requests the file `hardware_interface/hardware_interface.h`.

Where is this file ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57327/compiling-pr2_build_map_gazebo_demo-on-debian/) by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2013-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed `ros_control` from git to get this file.

---

Originally posted by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) with karma: 90 on 2013-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0